# folding over large BigQuery result

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there any easy way for me to do something like Ocaml's `fold_left` on a result of a BigQuery query, where each iteration corresponds to one row in the result?

What product or approach would be the easiest way? It would be great if:

- all I need to do is to supply the initial state and the 'folder' function
- preferably, I'd like to write the 'folder' function in a functional language
- I don't need to install any GCP package

Since I don't know which product or language would work, I cannot be more specific, but pseudocode would be like:

```
let my_init = []
let my_folder = fun state row ->
  // append for now, but it will be complicated. I need to do some set operations here. The point is that I need some way of transferring "state" across rows, when I iterate over rows in a predefined order.
  row.col1 :: state

let query = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1 ORDER BY timestamp"
query |> List.fold my_folder my_init
```

The result that I want to get from this simplified example is the final "state".

--- UPDATED ---

There is no bound on the number of rows---if we receive more, we get more rows. Typically, the number is more than a few millions but it can be larger than that.

Here's a simplified example that shows the major problem I'm encountering. We have a table with a few columns:

- timestamp
- user_id: a string id
- operation_json: a stringified JSON object, which is a list of operations, each of which corresponds to either:

  - add user_id to a set
  - remove user_id from a set

For example, the followings are valid rows:

```
----------+---------+----------------------------------------------
timestamp | user_id | operation_json
----------+---------+----------------------------------------------
1         | id1     | [ { "op": "add", "set": "set1" } ]
2         | id2     | [ { "op": "add", "set": "set1" } ]
3         | id1     | [ { "op": "add", "set": "set2" } ]
4         | id3     | [ { "op": "add", "set": "set2" } ]
5         | id1     | [ { "op": "remove", "set": "set1" } ]
----------+---------+----------------------------------------------
```

As a result, I'd like to get sets of users; i.e.,

```
set1 |-> { id2 }
set2 |-> { id1, id3 }
```

I thought fold_left-like operation would be convenient. The state would be map>, and the initial-state would be an empty map.

Comment: Can you give an example of a query and the result that you want?

Comment: I just edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: how large your large result? also, I would recommend presenting some practical case (with input, processing logic and desired output) rather than asking very generic question - so we will be able to help you further :o) - meantime, see update in my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help Mikhail. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below approach has nothing to do with `folding` per se, but rather attempt to translate your challenge into set-based one (which is more natural for when you dealing with sql) by identifying the latest op action for each user per set and if it is "remove" just eliminate that user from further consideration - if it is "add" just use the latest "add" for that user / set. This in assumption that there cannot be multiple consecutive "add" action for the same user / set - rather  - it can be add /remove / add and so on. of course this can be further adjusted based on real use case

So having above in mind - below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 ts, 'id1' user_id, '[ { "op": "add", "set": "set1" } ]' operation_json UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'id2', '[ { "op": "add", "set": "set1" } ]' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'id1', '[ { "op": "add", "set": "set2" } ]' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'id3', '[ { "op": "add", "set": "set2" } ]' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'id1', '[ { "op": "remove", "set": "set1" } ]' 
)
SELECT bin, STRING_AGG(user_id, ',' ORDER BY ts) result
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, bin, ARRAY_AGG(ts ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] ts
  FROM (
    SELECT ts, user_id, op, bin, LAST_VALUE(op) OVER(win) fin
    FROM (
      SELECT ts, user_id, 
        JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REGEXP_REPLACE(operation_json, r'^\[|\]$', ''), '$.op') op, 
        JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REGEXP_REPLACE(operation_json, r'^\[|\]$', ''), '$.set') bin
      FROM `project.dataset.table`
    )
    WINDOW win AS (
      PARTITION BY user_id, bin 
      ORDER BY ts 
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
  )
  WHERE fin = 'add'
  GROUP BY user_id, bin
)
GROUP BY bin
-- ORDER BY bin
```

output is

```
Row bin     result   
1   set1    id2  
2   set2    id1,id3
```

if to apply to below dummy data

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 ts, 'id1' user_id, '[ { "op": "add", "set": "set1" } ]' operation_json UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'id2', '[ { "op": "add", "set": "set1" } ]' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'id1', '[ { "op": "add", "set": "set2" } ]' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'id3', '[ { "op": "add", "set": "set2" } ]' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'id1', '[ { "op": "remove", "set": "set1" } ]' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'id1', '[ { "op": "add", "set": "set1" } ]' UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'id1', '[ { "op": "remove", "set": "set1" } ]' UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'id1', '[ { "op": "add", "set": "set1" } ]' UNION ALL 
  SELECT 9, 'id1', '[ { "op": "remove", "set": "set2" } ]' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 'id1', '[ { "op": "add", "set": "set2" } ]'
)
```

result will be

```
Row bin     result   
1   set1    id2,id1  
2   set2    id3,id1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm unsure if PARTITION works in our case, because it seems PARTITION does not work well with a large number of rows. I myself ran a query with PARTITION and it failed with memory exhaustion. When I redo the task, I'll apply your approach and keep you updated. The above solution looks great, and so I think I can consider this as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Below [quick and simple] example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION fold(arr ARRAY<INT64>, init INT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + parseInt(currentValue);
  return arr.reduce(reducer, 5);
""";
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [1, 2, 3, 4] arr, 5 initial_state UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 10 
)
SELECT id, fold(arr, initial_state) result
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

output is

```
Row id  result
1   1   15.0     
2   2   33.0
```

I think it is self-explanatory enough

See more for [`JS UDF`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions)

> folding list of rows

See below extension of above
Here you are assembling array from the result's rows before applying fold function (of course you have some [`limits`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#limits) for UDF here to have in mind and also on how big your ARRAY of rows can go, etc.

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION fold(arr ARRAY<INT64>, init INT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + parseInt(currentValue);
  return arr.reduce(reducer, 5);
""";
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 item UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1, 3 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1, 4 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 3 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 4 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 5 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 6 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 7 
)
SELECT id, fold(ARRAY_AGG(item), 5) result
FROM `project.dataset.table`  
GROUP BY id
```

Note, if you need to include more than one field from each row  - you can use ARRAY of STRUCT as below example

```
ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(id , item) ORDER by id)
```

Of course, you will need to adjust respectively signature of fold UDF

For example:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION fold(arr ARRAY<STRUCT<id INT64, item INT64>>, init INT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + parseInt(currentValue.item);
  return arr.reduce(reducer, 5);
""";
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1 item UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1, 3 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1, 4 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 3 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 4 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 5 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 6 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 7 
)
SELECT id, fold(ARRAY_AGG(t), 5) result
FROM `project.dataset.table` t 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I'm unsure if I understood this UDF correctly, but I think we are folding an array, not a list of rows. What I want is like: ```query-result |> List.fold my_folder my_init_state```, where `query-result` is a list of rows from a query.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. If I understood correctly, we build an array out of rows to make the input compatible with the UDF. I'll try but I guess it would fail with memory exhaustion. Actually, I tried to solve my problem (with simplified input) with PARTITION, but BigQuery failed with memory exhaustion.